# Mocking up an Azure Functions httpRequest form in Python

Tags: python, azure, function, unit-testing, httprequest

I'm writing tests for an Azure Function. The function reads multipart/form-data from the frontend, which it accesses using `data = dict(req.form)` where `req` is the func.HttpRequest. This works fine, and I can access the form data passed from the frontend. My problem is I can't seem to mock up the `req.form` object for my unit tests. I've written:

```
    req = func.HttpRequest(
        method="POST",
        headers={
            "x-ms-client-principal": my-test-user-object,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body=SOMETHING-GOES-HERE,
        url="/api/users"
    )
```

I've tried setting the body to a bytes object; this allows me to access the bytes object using `req.get_body()`. When I dump a JSON object I can get it with `req.get_json()`. But I can't figure out what to pass in so that I can access it using `req.form`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding the solution on [this blog post](https://julien.danjou.info/handling-multipart-form-data-python/). The `encode_multipart_formdata()` function described in the blog post allows for the creation of a mock form which can then be passed into the body of the HttpResponse object as follows:

```
body, content_type = encode_multipart_formdata({
    "username": os.environ["TEST_USERNAME1"],
    "email": os.environ["TEST_USER_EMAIL2"]
})
req = func.HttpRequest(
    method="POST",
    headers={
        "x-ms-client-principal": my-test-user-obj,
        "Content-Type": content_type
    },
    body=bytes(body, "utf-8"),
    url="/api/users"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the function in a below way to get the whole form in return response

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            'method': req.method,
            'url': req.url,
            'headers': dict(req.headers),
            'params': dict(req.params),
            'get_body': req.get_body().decode()
        })
    )
```

Or below [example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51524/flask.request.form) will make us to understand more about request.form to check the form data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I can already access the form data using `req.form`. What I need to do is _add_ some form data to the Azure Functions HttpRequest object. However, there is no parameter for form in the HttpRequest class, and I can't find documentation anywhere that describes the req.form parameter.